# ViewModel DisplayFormat Data Annotation not rendered in View

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using ASP.NET 5 Web Application Template I am trying to render a date in short date format. My viewmodel looks like this

```
    [Display(Name = "Subscription Expires")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime? SubscriptionExpires { get; set; }
```

My view looks like this

```
    <dt><label asp-for="SubscriptionExpires"></label>:</dt>
<dd>
    @Model.SubscriptionExpires
</dd>
```

However `@Model.SubscriptionExpires` renders in long date format. How do I get the view to render the date in short date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're directly outputting the date to the page, there is no opportunity for your data annotations to be considered.

HTML helpers look at those annotations, so you could simply do this:

`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubscriptionExpires)`

Alternatively simply format the date like this:

`@Model.SubscriptionExpires.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: Thank you @Mister Epic. 'ToShortDateString()' can't be used with nullable types but  '@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubscriptionExpires)' did the trick.